# How can I pass the response data successfully with function parameter in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

I am working on single page application, which is implementing based on Angular JS, JavaScript, JSON. I am calling one API then I am getting response and this response I want pass as a parameter in function call. I am sharing my code:

**abc.JS**

```
 Rh.get('------API URL----').then(function(response){    
    var data=response; 
          var item = '<a class="btn btn-xs" ng-click="sendDataPost('+"'"+JSON.stringify(data)+"'"+')" >'   
           '</a>'
    })

 $scope.sendDataPost = function (data) {
    alert("--");     
    console.log(data);
}
```

When I click on anchor tag then sendDataPost function is call and comes into the function definition($scope.sendDataPost). only [object Object] is showing in console. I am not able to pass JSON Data as a parameter. I have seen one link but still I am not able to do because in this link using onclick, but I am using ng-click.
[How to pass a json object in js funcion as a function parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23040849/how-to-pass-a-json-object-in-js-funcion-as-a-function-parameter)

***I am sharing my sample URL.***
**JSON SAMPLE URL**.

> http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cgwLpLgbyq?indent=2

**I editing my question. I solve when I am parsing the data in parameter, It is breaking.** **I am sharing screen shot**
[image]

sendDataPost parameter is breaking in console and  breaking html page. All json data display in HTML page. How can I pass the response data successfully with function parameter.

Comment: You can use `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()`

Comment: This is totally wrong approach creating html in controller. Assign response to scope property and use angular template in the view

Comment: I used both, But It is not working. Give some error unexpected token o.

Comment: @charlietfl. Actually I am implementing datatable. some html part implementing in controller as per plugin. json data is coming in response Can I pass this json data into parameter.

Comment: I edited my question. Please look.

Comment: use `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));` and check what is displaying

Comment: @Sravan It displaying in console only "[object Object]"

Comment: @Sravan If I put console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); in the Rh.get('------API URL----').then(function(response){   } then it is giving correctlymean without function call.

Comment: try sending, `ng-click="sendDataPost(data)">` and then in `sendDataPost` use `JSON.stringify(data)`

Comment: @Sravan I tried then it is giving me error in console.ng-click="sendDataPost([object ....

Comment: try using general `onclick="sendDataPost(data)"` and remove scope and convert it to a normal function

Comment: @Sravan I am using angular js. And when I suing onclick then It giving me sendDataPost is not defined. Page is already loaded into dom.

Comment: @Sravan Other way onclick has same problem. Parameter is breaking.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159025/discussion-between-sravan-and-v-sh).

Answer (score 0):

Why not you try to holding value in scope variable this below?

```
$scope.result = [];
Rh.get('------API URL----').then(function(response){    
    $scope.result = response;
})

$scope.sendDataPost = function (data) {    
    console.log(data);
}
```

in HTML

```
ng-click="sendDataPost(result)"
```